# Most efficient way to add individual digits of a number

Tags: algorithm, logic, primes

I am working on an algorithm to determine whether a given number is prime and came across this [website](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-a-Number-Is-Prime). But then I though of trying my own logic. I can easily eliminate numbers ending in 2,4,5,6,8 (and 0 for numbers above 5), so I am left with 1,3,7 and 9 as the possible last digit. Now, if the last digit is 3, I can add up the individual digits to check if it is divisible by 3. I don't want to perform modulus(%) operation and add them. Is there a much more efficient way to sum the digits in a decimal number? Maybe using bitwise operations... ?

Comment: Why only if the last digit is 3? 13 is not divisible by 3 while 21 is

Comment: @Fallen He means sum(all digits of integer) divisible by 3 so the integer is divisible by 3 { 21 , sum(1 + 2) = 3 % 3 = 0

Comment: @mohaned: I understand that but if he only checks the numbers who have last digit 3, it won't work.

Comment: @Fallen I really meant to ask about the way to add individual digits. Numbers ending with 3 was just an example.

Comment: If you want to do it for base 2, you can use population count. For base 10, you can refer to various formulas from [OEIS seqence # A007953](http://oeis.org/A007953)

Comment: Is your input a string of digits, or is it a binary value? I assume it must be a string, because it would make no sense to convert a binary value to a string of decimal digits just to add them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` or modulus operator would be faster than adding individul digits. But if you really want to do this, you can unroll your loop partly in such a way that multiples of 3 are escaped automatically.

For ex:

```
2 is prime
3 is prime
candidate = 5
while(candidate <= limit - 2 * 3)  // Unrolling loop for next 2 * 3 number
{
  if ( CheckPrime(candidate) ) candidate is prime;
  candidate += 2;
  if ( CheckPrime(candidate) ) candidate is prime;
  candidate += 4;  // candidate + 2 is multiple of 3 (9, 15, 21 etc)
}
if(candidate < limit) CheckPrime(candidate);
```

In above method we are eliminating multiples of 3 instead of checking the divisibility of 3 by adding the digits.

You had a good observation. Incidentally it is called [wheel factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) to find prime. I have done for `wheel size = 6` (2*3), but you can do the same for larger wheel size also, for ex: 30(2*3*5). The snippet above is also called as all prime number are of type 6N±1.
(because 6N+3 is multiple of 3)

p.s. Not all numbers ending at 2 and 5 are composite. Number 2 and 5 are exceptions.

Comment: @TylerDurden Depends on how did you implement your big num library. On an average bignum implementation, still modulus should be faster IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following but i think modulus is fastest way :-

```
1. 2^n mod 3 = 1 if n is even and = 2 if n is odd
2. odd bits and even bits cancel each out as their sum is zero modulo 3
4. so the absolute difference of odd and even bits is the remainder
5. As difference might be again greater than 3 you need to again calculate modulo 3 
6. step 5 can be done recursively
```

**Pseudo code :-**

```
int modulo3(int num) {

  if(num<3)
     return num;

  int odd_bits = cal_odd(num);
  int even_bits = cal_even(num);

  return module3(abs(even_bits-odd_bits));
}
```